# (Angular, TypeScript) Create new function from string that has if condition (without eval())

Tags: javascript, angular, if-statement

How can I create a new function from a string when the string contains if condition?
The string will comes from outside but in the dummy example below everything is hardcoded to be easier.

```js
let f1: number = 1;
let f2: number = 0;
let condition: string = 'if(this.f1===1){this.f2 = 1}';

let result = this.createFn(condition);

createFn(param: string) {
  return new Function('return ' + param)();
  // or return new Function(param)();
}
```

Of course this is not working and I'm searching a way to do it.
I don't want to use eval().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Passing a string to the constructor of `Function` is almost the same as using `eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Function).

To safely execute arbitrary code in JavaScript you need to have a JavaScript interpreter written in JavaScript which will then execute the received string in a sandbox environment. A quick google search yields this package: https://github.com/NeilFraser/JS-Interpreter.

Others who faced this issue have decided to implement themselves a domain-specific subset of a programming language to then allow the strings to execute that language's code. e.g. [SAP's SAPUI5/OpenUI5 solution for the Expression Binding they have](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/base/ExpressionParser.js).

Comment: I already read these and similar articles. All simple examples with a,b and return a+b are fine but when you try to add a condition to them its not working.

Comment: Actually the solution is in the 1st link that you provided:
 let f1 = 1; let f2 = 0; let newFn = new Function('f1', 'f2', 'if(f1===1){return f1} return f2'); f2 = newFn(f1, f2);